# Topology of the space $C[0,\infty)$ of continuous functions.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Consider the space $C[0,\infty)$ of continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$. Consider the following two topologies.

The first topology, denoted $\tau_1$ is generated by cylinder sets, i.e. sets of the form:
$\{\omega\in C[0,\infty) \text{ such that }(\omega_{t_1},..\omega_{t_2})\in A_1\times...\times A_n\}$,
where $A_1,..A_n$ are open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

The second topology, denoted $\tau_2$ is the metric topology induced by the following metric:
$d(\omega_1,\omega_2) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\sup_{0\leq t \leq n}(|\omega_1(t)-\omega_2(t)|\wedge 1)$.

What I'm trying to answer is whether the two topologies coincide. I have managed to show that $\tau_1\subseteq\tau_2$. I'm not sure how to proceed with the other direction.

Any hint or direction or reference material would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: They don't coincide

Comment: @Bananach Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do not coincide. For instance, pointwise convergence implies convergence in $\tau_1$, but not in $\tau_2$.

For example, let $h(x)$ be $1$ on $[2; 3]$ and $0$ on $[0; 1] \cup [4; \infty)$. Let $f_n(x) = h(\frac{x}{n})$. Then $f_n \to_{\tau_1} 0$ (as for any $x$ for all sufficiently large $n$ we have $f_n(x) = 0$), but $d(f_n, 0) \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @VietDang So, why not accepting this answer?

Comment: @Jochen I did now. I'm not very familiar with the site.